# Onlongclick Remove visibility of icon from Grid View

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I am currently a newbie in android programming.
and i am having an issue of using grid view in my code.
My code purpose is to swap an icon with another icon within a grid view.
Currently, i am implementing onlongclick method to start and drag the icon around.
I have 4 icons in 1 column, which comes from an array.
Each view will be invisible when the onlongclick method is triggered.
however, when i tried it onto the first icon, the view become invisible and the dragging method didn't start. Could you please tell me where i did wrong in this part.
here are the error log.

```
08-04 22:53:50.460: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25556): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-04 22:53:50.460: E/SpannableStringBuilder(25556): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556): Unable to initiate drag
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.view.View.startDrag(View.java:16249)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at com.example.robotbehaviorui.CustomBehaviorActivity$MyLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(CustomBehaviorActivity.java:166)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3143)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3093)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-04 22:53:51.990: E/View(25556):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my onlongclick listener

```
private final class MyLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
        int arg2, long arg3) {
    try{
        Toast.makeText(CustomBehaviorActivity.this, "OnLongClick:  "+(CharSequence) v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE); 

        System.out.println("INDEX: "+ conditionsPanel.indexOfChild(v));
        System.out.println("SIZE: "+ conditionsList.size());
        System.out.println("COUNT: "+ conditionsAdapter.getCount());
        //pop up remove area
        deleteView.setVisibility(deleteView.VISIBLE);

    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("NullPointerException: "+npe.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception exe){
        System.out.println("NullPointerException: "+exe.getMessage());
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue...haven't yet been able to find a fix.